# Comparing string hashes on different machines

Tags: c#, hash, char, compare

- I have a bunch of IDs, that are in the String form, like `"enemy1", "enemy2"`.
- I want to save a progress, depends on how many of each enemies I killed. For that goal I use a dictionary like `{ { "enemy1", 0 }, { "enemy2", 1 } }`.
- Then I want to share player's save between few machines he can play into (like PC and laptop) via network (serialize it in JSON file first). For size decreasing and perfomance inreasing, i use hashes instead full string, using that alg (becouse MDSN said, that default hash alg can be different on different machines):

```
int hash_ = 0;
public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        if(hash_ == 0)
        { 
          hash_ = 5381;
          foreach(var ch in id_)
            hash_ = ((hash_ << 5) + hash_) ^ ch;
        }
        return hash_;
    }
```

So, the question is: is that alg in C# will return the same results in any machine player will use.

---

UPD: in comments i note that the main part of question was unclear.
So. If i can guarantee that all files before deserialization will be in the same encoding, is char representation on every machine that player can use will be the same and operation `^ ch` will give same result? I mean WinX64/WinX32/Mac/Linux/... machines

Comment: Yes, that algorithm will give the same result on every machine. You shouldn't assume that two strings with equal hashes are necessarily equal though. But it's unclear to me what this has to do with the rest of the question. How are you going to use the hash afterwards? (If you want something *close* to a guarantee of uniqueness, I'd use a cryptographic hash on the file instead, e.g. using SHA-256 or SHA-512. It wouldn't be unreasonable to assume that two files with the same SHA hash are the same.)

Comment: If you are creating your own hash code like that, then it will be the same on each machine. However, if you rely on any default implementation of GetHashCode() then it isn't guaranteed.

Comment: @JonSkeet, thanks. I assume that it was unclear, but the main part was about char representation in C#. If I can guarantee that all JSONs before deseralization will be in the same encoding, is char representation on Winx86/Winx64/Unix/MAC... machines will be the same?

Comment: Yes, a `char` is always a UTF-16 code unit. But it's still not clear to me why you'd use this approach rather than taking a cryptographic hash of the file.

Comment: @JonSkeet it doesn't really make sense because i have not a big number of that string entries and 6% of intersections is okay for me. But it makes sence at all and it is important note, thanks.

Comment: @JonSkeet morover, I have one file with serialized dictionary and cannot hash each _file_ becouse I have only one.

Comment: It's still entirely unclear to me what you're doing with that hash afterwards then...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, that code will give the same result on every platform, for the same input. A `char` is a UTF-16 code unit, regardless of platform, and any given `char` will convert to the same `int` value on every platform. As normal with hash codes computed like this, you shouldn't assume that equal hash codes implies equal original values. (It's unclear how you're intending to use the hash, to be honest.)

I would point out that your code isn't thread-safe though - if two threads call `GetHashCode` at basically the same time, one may see a value of 0 (and therefore start hashing) whereas the second may see an *interim* result (as computed by the first thread) and assume that's the final hash. If you really believe caching is important here (and I'd test that first) you should compute the complete hash using a local variable, then copy it to the field only when you're done.

Comment: It will something like "find entry with THAT hash code and increment its stat by 1". Or "get entry with THAT hash code and show its stat on the screen". Expected entries count approximately would be less that 1000.

Comment: @DenisIlyutin: That sounds like you're using the hash as an ID then - which means there are issues with collisions, unless you also have the original data present - in which case hashing wouldn't help with your size anyway. Why not just create an *actual* ID?

Comment: because i want to hide actual ID and, moreover, it won't affect on size at runtime (only on negative side), but will affect on the size after serialization in JSON on my mind (I know that it is unnessesary optimisation in my case, but it still research). 
And, as I know, `int` operations are cheaper that `string` operation at runtime, so it is an optimisation in case of cache hash value.

Comment: and what about collisions - it is very unlikely situation in my case and i think i can disregard it

Comment: @DenisIlyutin: I would *strongly* advise against just ignoring hash collisions, *particularly* if you're not using a hash that's designed to make it really, really unlikely that you see duplicate values. If you don't want to expose some internal ID, just generate a new one (e.g. with `Guid.NewGuid`). At the moment you're using a hash as if it were an ID, when hash codes like this are *specifically* not designed for that use case. (Also, I'm aware that caching is an optimization - but your current approach to caching is not thread safe.)

Comment: @DenisIlyutin Hash collisions are not as unlikely as you think. Hashing to a 32-bit integer, your likelihood of getting a collision is 50% after only 70,000 or so items. I don't recall where the 25% and 10% marks are, except that they're much lower than 70,000. If you use a 32-bit hash code for an ID, you *will* end up with collisions.

Comment: Thanks for your answers, i think i will change hashes for some another id's.